# Remove 'standalone="yes"' from generated XML

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, xml-binding

Do you know of a JAXB setting to prevent **standalone="yes"** from being generated in the resulting XML?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

Comment: Why is that a problem?

Comment: @Kornel in my project that to get used with Tibco and WebMethod, its will generate error because standalone=yes is not recognized

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This property:

```java
marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlDeclaration", false);
```

...can be used to have no:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

However, I wouldn't consider this best practice.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. I would agree it is best practice to include the line, but a web service I am interfacing with does not expect it.

Comment: Good that it works, but FWIW, service is broken if it can not accept legal xml, so it's probably good to file a bug report against it.

Comment: Doesn't work with JAXB in JDK1.6. See so_mv's answer for correct solution.

Comment: That explodes in flight : exception.

Comment: @sversch : you can try property class : "com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders"

Comment: @baybora.oren "com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders" fails as well on Java 1.7.0_51 with a javax.xml.bind.PropertyException.

Answer (score 124):

in JAXB that is part of JDK1.6

```java
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
```

Comment: This does not give the expected result. This removes all the XML declaration line. What I want is just removing the `standalone` attribute in the XML declaration.

Comment: If you wonder why this isn't working for you, just like I did, then the answer is that the effect depends on which marshal api you are using.  For marshal(Object,Outputstream) and marshal(Object,Writer) this works as suggested here. For marshal(Object, Node) it has no effect. For the remaining marshal api implications have a look [here](https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.4/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html) under the Supported Properties section.

Comment: doesn't work on java 11. the whole fragment <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> goes away

Answer (score 68):

You can either use

```java
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
```

or

```java
marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlDeclaration", false)
```

to disable the default XML declaration, and then add your custom XML declaration,

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

by

```java
marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders",
      "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
```

to the generated xml, thus avoiding the **standalone="yes"** property.

Comment: The "setProperty" with "xmlDeclaration" explodes in flight : exception.

Comment: The "setProperty" line with "xmlHeaders" fails too. PropertyException. So this is not a solution.

Comment: which version of java and jaxb are you using?

Comment: @WarFox The setProperty with xmlHeaders command does not work with jdk1.6.0_24 and JAXB version 2.1

Comment: Regardless of java6 or java7 I had to add 'internal', ie marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");

Comment: doesn't work on java 11. the whole fragment <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> goes away

Answer (score 7):

just if someone else is still struggeling with this problem, you may consider using

```
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
```

to remove all of the XML declaration and just write your own `String` at the beginning of your output stream / method

Answer (score 6):

If you make document dependent on `DOCTYPE` (e.g. use named entities) then it will stop being standalone, thus `standalone="yes"` won't be allowed in XML declaration.

However standalone XML can be used anywhere, while non-standalone is problematic for XML parsers that don't load externals.

I don't see how this declaration could be a problem, other than for interoperability with software that doesn't support XML, but some horrible regex soup.

Comment: Exactly, any allegedly xml-processing system that barfs on xml declaration seems highly suspicious.

Comment: In what way does it answer the question?

Comment: How does one make the document depend on `DOCTYPE`?

Answer (score 5):

```
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>");
```

This worked for me with JDK1.7. standalone=\"no\" can be removed to get only rest of the xml part

Comment: error : javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: name: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders value: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Answer (score 5):

If you are using only the default javax.xml package, you could set the JAXB_FRAGMENT option of the marshaller to 'true' (this omits the default xml processing instruction) and use the writeProcessingInstruction method of the XMLStreamWriter to insert your own:

```
xmlStreamWriter.writeProcessingInstruction("xml", "version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"");
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty( Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(object, xmlStreamWriter);
xmlStreamWriter.writeEndDocument();
```

Answer (score 3):

just try

```
private String marshaling2(Object object) throws JAXBException, XMLStreamException {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(object.getClass());
    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    writer.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n");
    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(object, writer);
    return writer.toString();
  }
```

Comment: Cool, work on Java 11

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Java 1.8 and JAXB 2.3.1

First, be sure to be using java 1.8 in pom.xml

```
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
```

Then in source code I used: (the key was the internal part)

```
// remove standalone=yes
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:
    marshaller.setProperty("jaxb.fragment", Boolean.TRUE);

It works for me on Java 8

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a high enough "reputation" to have the "privilege" to comment. ;-)

@Debasis, note that the property you've specified:

```
"com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders"
```

should be:

```
"com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders" (without the "internal", which are not meant to be used by the public)
```

If I use the "internal" property as you did, I get a *javax.xml.bind.PropertyException*

Answer (score 1):

In case you are getting property exception, add the following configuration:

```
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders",
              "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlDeclaration", Boolean.FALSE);
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`

but want this: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Just do:

```
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting PropertyException when using:

```
marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
```

Instead **what helped me** was setting JAXB_FRAGMENT to true and then writing the custom header using:

```
marshaller.setProperty("org.glassfish.jaxb.xmlHeaders", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<!DOCTYPE note SYSTEM>"
```