# Remove standalone="yes" from jaxb generated xml

Tags: java, xml, formatting, jaxb

```
public final String getMessage() {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext;
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            try {
                jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Login.class);        
                Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            
                jaxbMarshaller.setProperty("jaxb.encoding", "ISO-8859-1");                      
                        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(this, sw);
            } catch (JAXBException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return sw.toString();
        }
```

This is the code what I'm using..and I'm getting output as following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
```

Here I want to remove standalone="yes" and want output as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

I checked link
[Remove 'standalone="yes"' from generated XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277996/jaxb-remove-standalone-yes-from-generated-xml)
but answers here are removing complete

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

part

I don't want that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple of issues that need to be addressed in your question:

**ISSUE #1 - Encoding**

The `"jaxb.encoding"` property when sets directly affects the encoding when the output is an `OutputStream`.  If you are using an output that (such as `Writer`) that is reponsible for handling its own encoding then you need to make sure that you handle that as part of the `Writer`.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/jaxb-and-java-io-files-streams-readers.html

**ISSUE #2 - `standalone="yes"`**

You can create a StAX (JSR-173) `XMLStreamWriter` to wrap your `StringWriter` for your XML output and marshal to that.

```java
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.stream.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class Login {

    private JAXBContext jaxbContext;
    private XMLOutputFactory xmlOutputFactory;

    public Login() {
        try {
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Login.class);
            xmlOutputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Login demo = new Login();
        System.out.println(demo.getMessage());
    }

    public final String getMessage() {
        try {
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty("jaxb.encoding", "ISO-8859-1");
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            XMLStreamWriter xmlStreamWriter = xmlOutputFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(baos, (String) jaxbMarshaller.getProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING));
            xmlStreamWriter.writeStartDocument((String) jaxbMarshaller.getProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING), "1.0");
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(this, xmlStreamWriter);
            xmlStreamWriter.writeEndDocument();
            xmlStreamWriter.close();
            return new String(baos.toByteArray());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

**Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><login></login>
```

---

**ALTERNATE APPROACH**

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

There are other JAXB (JSR-222) providers such as MOXy that do not output `standalone="yes"` as part of the XML Output that you can use.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple solution for this problem. Disable the auto generated header by:

```
marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlDeclaration", false);
```

This will disable the auto generated header, now we can add our custom headers like this:

```
marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>");
```

As whole this code looks like:

```
marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlDeclaration", false);
marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>");
```