# JAXB - XML declaration not being created

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am using the following code to create XML using JAXB, however when the XML is created the XML declaration is not included.

Code:

```
ServletContext ctx = getServletContext();
            String filePath = ctx.getRealPath("/xml/"+username + ".xml");

            File file = new File(filePath);
            JAXBContext context= JAXBContext.newInstance("com.q1labs.qa.xmlgenerator.model.generatedxmlclasses");
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = context.createMarshaller();

            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(test, os);

            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                             "attachment;filename=xmlTest.xml");

            InputStream is = ctx.getResourceAsStream("/xml/"+username + ".xml");
```

XML Declaration:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`

How can I get it to output the XML declaration?

Comment: Note sure if this is related, but why are you specifying the content type as "text/plain" and not as "text/xml" or "application/xml"?

Comment: Also note that writing to a file is probably not be thread-safe. Why not using a StringWriter instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write to a file, you can do it in-memory like this:

```
...
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(test, os);

StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>");
content.append(os.toString());
System.out.println("jaxb xml = " + os.toString());

response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=xmlTest.xml");

String generatedXML = content.toString();
System.out.println("full xml = " + generatedXML);
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(generatedXML);

final int bufferSize = 4096;
OutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(), bufferSize);
for (int length = 0; (length = is.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
  output.write(buffer, 0, length);
}
output.flush();
output.close();
```

BTW, you should consider using UTF-8.

Comment: If I write it to memory can users still download it? If so, how?

Comment: There, I just updated the answer with a "copy input stream to output stream". The solution needs some exception handling, this is all done by memory.

Comment: It's causing this to be added into the start of the XML when it should only be the second XML tag added, it is also causing the XML to formatt oddly putting everything onto one line.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`

Comment: It looks to me that JAXB does add the XML declaration (the second one). I have updated the answer with couple `println()` statements so check the output. As for the all-in-one-line you did leave `Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT` set to `true`?

Comment: When it is printed out to the file the XML declaration is missing, however when I print out to the console it is there. This is what I'm printing out:
`StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer(os.toString());
      System.out.println(content);`

Comment: Very strange :-) No idea why it's happening though. But if you leave out the XML declaration from `new StringBuffer(...)` you should get a good XML, right?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, by default my XML is opening in Chrome which does not show the declaration however when I opened it in notepad it does. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered pretty well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277996/jaxb-remove-standalone-yes-from-generated-xml)

To sum up, all you should need to do is this:

```
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.FALSE);
```

Comment: From reading that question it looks like that line is supposed to remove the XML declaration?

Comment: If you make it an XML Fragment then you are telling JAXB that the XML you marshal will be incorporated into a larger XML document.  When its TRUE, you signal that JAXB is creating the full XML document so it includes the declaration.

Comment: The actual answer without any hacks!