# Altering the XML header produced by the JAXB marshaller

Tags: java, jaxb

I am currently using the following code to marshal an object into an xml string

```
    JAXBContext context;

    try {
        context = JAXBContext.newInstance(heartbeat.getClass());
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();

        heartbeat.setHeader(header);
        heartbeat.setHeartbeatEvent(event);

        marshaller.marshal(heartbeat, writer);
        String stringXML = writer.toString();
        return stringXML;

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Problems generating XML in specified "
                + "encoding, underlying problem is " + e.getMessage(),
                e);
    }
```

Which produces the following header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

My desired output is the following

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
```

By adding this to the marshaller

```
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.FALSE);
marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders", "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>");
```

I receive

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><?xml version="1.0"?>
```

and changing the JAXB_FRAGMENT property to TRUE removes the header entirely. I have been following the [JAXB - Remove 'standalone="yes"' from generated XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277996/jaxb-remove-standalone-yes-from-generated-xml) thread attempting to solve the problem but I have had no luck so far. Can someone please give me some insight on how to get my desired header from the JAXB marshaller?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When marshalling to an `OutputStream` using a combination of the following produces the expected output.

```
    marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders", "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>");
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
```

The problem you are seeing occurs when you marshal to a `Writer`, which appears to be a bug in the JAXB reference implementation.  You can raise an issue at the link below:

- https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB/

---

You could always do:

```
JAXBContext context;

try {
    context = JAXBContext.newInstance(heartbeat.getClass());
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    writer.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>");
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);

    heartbeat.setHeader(header);
    heartbeat.setHeartbeatEvent(event);

    marshaller.marshal(heartbeat, writer);
    String stringXML = writer.toString();
    return stringXML;

} catch (JAXBException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Problems generating XML in specified "
            + "encoding, underlying problem is " + e.getMessage(),
            e);
}
```

---

[**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/#moxy) also supports the `com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders` and it works correctly when marshalling to a `Writer` (I'm the MOXy lead)

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Comment: I get a `PropertyException` when setting the `sun` property.

Comment: On MOXy?  Which version are you using?

Comment: No MOxy. I assumed the property was used with the Java implementation.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - I am able to set the property on the `Marshaller` from the JAXB implementation included in JDK 1.7.0_25-b15 for the Mac (as well as MOXy).

Comment: I'm on JDK 1.7.0_21 on Windows. The exception occurs at `at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.setProperty(Unknown Source)` and `at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.setProperty(Unknown Source)`. It's not one of the properties it looks for.

Comment: For propertyException see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33199912/1386911

Comment: Daniel Hári proposed in an edit that with newer JDKs the property to set is `"com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders"`.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me

> `marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders", 
>   "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");`

Comment: "com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders" works when using jaxb from jdk 1.8 (at least on windows with java 1.8.0_60)

Answer (score 3):

In JAXB 3.0.1 the above mentioned constants cause a PropertyException:

```
 jakarta.xml.bind.PropertyException: name: com.sun.xml.bind.xmlDeclaration value: false
```

In this case, the XML preamble can be configured with these marshaller constants:

```
marshaller.setProperty("org.glassfish.jaxb.xmlHeaders", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>");
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
```

- https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jaxb-ri/3.0.0/docs/ch05.html