# Jaxb marshaller setproperty XSLT throws PropertyException

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I try to set XSL property for my marshaller like this ([which I copied from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153219/making-jaxb-generate-an-xml-processing-instruction)) :

```
marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders",
                "<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href=\"" +
                        xslFileName +
                        "\" ?>");
```

But it causes `javax.xml.bind.PropertyException` with this message :

```
name: com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders value: <?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href="decathlon.xsl" ?>
```

"very informative"

Sorry, but I cannot elaborate more, frankly I have no idea what causes this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add DOCTYPE and xml processing instructions when marshalling with JAXB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919294/how-to-add-doctype-and-xml-processing-instructions-when-marshalling-with-jaxb)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919294/how-to-add-doctype-and-xml-processing-instructions-when-marshalling-with-jaxb#answer-2919356), which solved my problem. All i had to do to replace the `com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders` property with `com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue while upgrading to Springboot 3 with JDK 17.  I solved the issue with:

```
marshaller.setProperty("org.glassfish.jaxb.xmlHeaders", "<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='/xsl/transformation.xsl' ?>");

groupId:jakarta.xml.bind, artifactId:jakarta.xml.bind-api, version:4.0.0
groupId:org.glassfish.jaxb,artifactId:jaxb-runtime, version:4.0.3, scope:runtime
```

Comment: Nice find, I also used this for Spring Boot 3 upgrade now!