# Remove portion of XML declarations, encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, java-io

I'm splitting an incoming xml file using JAXB.
I know this seems like a duplicate thread, However

Expected,

`<?xml version="1.0"?>`

Actual,

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`

I tried using JAXB_FRAGMENT which completely removes the first line

```
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
```

And

```
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>");
```

with and without `Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT`

FYI, I'm using StringWriter

```
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ExportDocument.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);//

        //jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);

        //jaxbMarshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>");

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(employee, sw);
        String xmlContent = sw.toString();

        System.out.println(xmlContent);
```

Comment: Is the emitted document in fact *not* effectively standalone?  Or else, why is this an issue?

Comment: No, I don't want to enforce validity constraints with external DTD. Incoming XML has no encoding and standalone fields. So the spit xmls need not have them.

Comment: Ok, but (1) that's not the effect of `standalone="no"` (the default), and (2) unless there's a `DOCTYPE` declaration, there is no external DTD to validate against anyway.  In fact, `standalone="yes"` seems closer to what you want (though it doesn't disable validation against an external DTD, either).

Comment: I see,what about the encoding part? Does it effect in anyway?

Comment: The encoding part specifies the character encoding of the document.  You could safely omit it in this case because UTF-8 is the default anyway, but it is not harmful.  It is unlikely to be worth expending effort on suppressing that.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, however incoming xml has only version, not having them in split xmls makes more sense. Still wanna know how I can remove them.

Comment: I recognize that my comments do not answer the question posed.  That's why they're comments, not an answer.  But you should take them as a frame challenge: instead of trying to solve the problem of getting rid of (at worst) harmless attributes, consider solving the problem of making needless work for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually looking for the exact same thing and this is what I found
[Altering the XML header produced by the JAXB marshaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451870/altering-the-xml-header-produced-by-the-jaxb-marshaller)